# VideoView size doesn't fit in the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview

My video has dimensions: height 2048 width 1152
What to change to make it visible at all on every screen?
My video currently goes to an edge then it is smaller than screen. How to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you can use this

```
 <VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </VideoView>
```

Comment: Worked! You saved my life :P

Comment: In this way, if you have a video with smaller resolutions (i.e. 320x480) and you want to apply in larger screen, it will stretch the video to fit all the screen. But in this case I think it will work fine.

Comment: well, its working but i couldn't understand why its not working under other layouts like frame layout and constraint layout if you have solution using other layouts as well please share.